# Karate - How to use java execution hook for parallel execution

Tags: karate

I am trying to implement a `beforeStep` execution hook.

It has been successfuly with

```
                Results result = Runner
                .path("/Users/FindStoryByID.feature")
                .hook(new KarateExecutionHockExample()).parallel(1);
```

How to achieve such feat if we want to use the parallel execution like below? I cannot seem to chain the `.hook` with `Runner.parallel`

```
    Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 20);
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number / argument to `parallel()` (the last method on the builder) is the number of parallel threads.

```
Results results = Runner.path(path).hook(new MandatoryTagHook()).parallel(10);
```

Here is an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/8a41ff51801f66e563346e3a182a2e57cae8f977

Comment: Thanks Peter!

This might be a little bit out of line from my original question. But how do we pass on custom tags to run to the `Runner.path()` builder API?  I mean the `-Dkarate.options="--tags $tags"` we can pass through terminal

Thanks a lot as always

Comment: @Raymond just do `Runner.path(path).tags(tags)` etc, try it

Comment: This is what I've done so far:

`Results result = Runner.path("classpath:features")`
                `.hook(new KarateExecutionHockExample()).parallel(10);`

The above runs just fine, but it will run all the existing feature files.

I haven't figured out how to pass the tags programatically using the `-Dkarate.options`

Thank you

Comment: @Raymond can you re-read my prev comment. `tags` can be a set of strings like this `tags("~@ignore,@smoke")`

Comment: Ah my bad. Thanks so much @Peter, it works like a charm!